# Selenium не работает как надо

Tags: python, веб-программирование, selenium, test-automation

Доброе время суток друзья и коллеги. Делаю автоматизацию сайта на **Питоне** через **Selenium**. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не все элементы сайта прописаны как следуют(есть опыт в верстке, может я ошибаюсь) в следствии чего селениум не отрабатывает методы клика или поиска нужного мне элемента сайта по **XPath**! Это реально косяк вебщиков или сам селениум такой по сути (склоняюсь иногда к мысли что я горе разраб, и не только руки у меня кривые). Поделитесь своим мнением на счёт этого пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как же я намучился с этим XPath и поиском веб элементов, все работало плохо и находило через раз.

Пока не увидел, что javascript можно запускать через selenium.

```
button = driver.execute_script("""
    let button = document.querySelector('.right-actions-overflow-menu-trigger');
    console.log('button:',button);
    return button;
             """)
            
button.click()
```

Попробуй, надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Очень хорошо, очень)

Comment: спасибо @Zhenia попробую обязательно