# Selenium Python: Не удается найти и нажать на кнопку

Tags: python, selenium

На [**данной странице**](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/228411992) (или любой другой опрос с возможностью выбора одного варианта) есть кнопка **"Голосовать"**, на которую нужно нажать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала нужно выбрать первый вариант ответа, чтобы кнопка стала доступна:

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.l_IR7').click()
```

Это работает.

---

После этого нажимаю на кнопку, но ничего не происходит.

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._C7zL').click()
```

Пробовал получать через `xpath`, и в результате получаю ошибку:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/a/div').click()
```

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/a/div"}
```

Я пробовал также выставлять задержку и ждать средствами `selenium`, на случай если кнопка может быть невидима какое-то время. Но результатов это не дало.

---

Код:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

# сохранить cookie
def save_cookies():
    input('\n\nНажмите Enter если можно сохранять куки\n\n')
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl","wb"))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://otvet.mail.ru/question/228411992')

# раскомментировать строку ниже, чтобы сохранить cookie (нужно нажать enter в консоли после авторизации)
# save_cookies()

# загрузка cookie
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()

# выбор первого варианта голосования
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.l_IR7').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/a/div').click()
```

---

**С чем это может быть связано и как нажать на эту кнопку?**

Comment: Селениум плохо находит веб элементы, как правило код срабатывает до того как html полностью загрузился, но есть javascript и его можно запускать через селениум.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385154/selenium-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be/1385177#1385177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что элементов с названием `._C7zL` было около 10, а кнопка была под индексом `2`, поэтому решение для этой ситуации будет выглядеть так:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._C7zL')[2].click()
```