# Нажатие кнопок на сайте с помощью скрипта python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, library

Как автоматизировать нажатие кнопок на сайте, т.е что я имею ввиду.
У меня есть сайт и я хочу протестировать как работают кнопки на нем. Какие нужно использовать python библиотеки для того чтобы написать скрипт на питоне который автоматизирует нажатие кнопок в определенной последовательности.

Comment: Посмотрите `selenium` - это для автоматизации действий в браузере. Я недавно задавал вопрос по этой библиотеке, там есть пример рабочего кода, можете изучить или почитать какое-нибудь руководство. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1390112/selenium-python-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83/1390229#1390229

Comment: обязательно ознакомлюсь