# Как извлечь текст из span, если нет class?

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, selenium

Буду благодарен за подсказку о том, как извлечь текст из тега span, если нет class.

Код:

```
<div class="product-tile__wrapper product-tile__wrapper--name">
    <div class="product-tile-name">
        <p class="product-tile-name__text">
            <span data-at-product-tile-brand="" class="product-tile-name__text--brand">
      DOLCE&amp;GABBANA </span>
            <br>
            <span data-at-product-tile-title=""> Набор Light Blue Eau De Toilette
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пробую:

```
brand_names = product.find('span', class_='product-tile-name__text--brand').get_text()
product_names = product.find()
```

brand_names извлекается отлично, а вот с product_names - проблема...

Comment: посмотрите здесь, это не ответ на ваш вопрос, но должно помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1385154/selenium-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be/1385177#1385177

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = '''<div class="product-tile__wrapper product-tile__wrapper--name">
    <div class="product-tile-name">
        <p class="product-tile-name__text">
            <span data-at-product-tile-brand="" class="product-tile-name__text--brand">
      DOLCE&amp;GABBANA </span>
            <br>
            <span data-at-product-tile-title=""> Набор Light Blue Eau De Toilette
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'html.parser')
brand, title = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('span')]
print(brand, title, sep='\n')

brand, title = soup.find('p').stripped_strings
print(brand, title, sep='\n')

DOLCE&GABBANA
Набор Light Blue Eau De Toilette
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло очевидное:

```
product_name = product.find('p', class_='product-tile-name__text')
                      .find_all('span')[1].text
```